# Merge Syntax SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, merge

I am basically trying to do the thing from MYSQL where it is INSERT and ON DUPLICATE, etc.

However, I am getting an error with my 'merge' syntax.  This stored procedure takes a variable "@ID" which is a guid and looks in the table to see if it exists already -- if it does, insert a new entry, otherwise update the existing.  I can't figure out what is wrong here!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DigitalTool_InsertUpdate2
(@ID uniqueidentifier, @TOOL_ID uniqueidentifier, @INPUT_ID uniqueidentifier)

AS

MERGE 
INTO  DigitalTool as target
USING (SElECT @ID,@TOOL_ID,@INPUT_ID) as source(id, tool_id, input_id) 
ON (target.ID = source.id)
when matched then  
 update
  set TOOL_ID = source.tool_id,
    INPUT_ID = source.input_id
when not matched then
insert ( ID, TOOL_ID, INPUT_ID)
    values ( NEWID(), source.tool_id, source.input_id)

END
GO
```

Help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What is `@TOOL_ID` and `@INPUT_ID`? Why is it used as a text value in one case and apparently as a parameter in another?

Comment: @TOOL_ID and @INPUT_ID come in as parameters and update the field if the ID is unique to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TSQL You can use the EXISTS keyword to determine whether a record is found as follows.

```
IF EXISTS(
 SELECT 1
 FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE ITEM='somevalue' AND ENTERDATE='12/31/1999')
    --Update Statement
    UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET ITEM='anothervalue'
    WHERE ITEM='somevalue' AND ENTERDATE='12/31/1999'
ELSE
    --Insert Statement
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (ITEM, ENTERDATE)
    VALUES
    ('somevalue', '12/31/1999')
```

Comment: if i could shake your hand i would, but you're out of arms reach right now. thanks!

Comment: You could also do an [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert) by doing an Update, if @@rowcount=0, Insert.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like

```
    MERGE 
INTO  DigitalTool as target
USING (SElECT @ID,@TOOL_ID,@INPUT_ID) as source(id, tool_id, input_id) 
ON (target.id = source.id)
when matched then  
 update
  set TOOL_ID = source.tool_id,
    INPUT_ID = source.input_id
when not matched then
insert ( ID, TOOL_ID, INPUT_ID)
    values ( NEWID(), source.tool_id, source.input_id)
```

**Update.**

There are couple of mistakes in your procedure  (`BEGIN` missed, as well as semicolon at the end). It should look:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DigitalTool_InsertUpdate2
(@ID uniqueidentifier, @TOOL_ID uniqueidentifier, @INPUT_ID uniqueidentifier)  
AS
BEGIN 
 MERGE 
 INTO  DigitalTool as target
 USING (SElECT @ID,@TOOL_ID,@INPUT_ID) as source(id, tool_id, input_id) 
 ON (target.ID = source.id)
 when matched then  
 update
 set TOOL_ID = source.tool_id,
   INPUT_ID = source.input_id
 when not matched then
 insert ( ID, TOOL_ID, INPUT_ID)
  values ( NEWID(), source.tool_id, source.input_id);
END;
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error with this code :(. what is the select supposed to be selecting? the column names?  bcuz they do not use the @ in the actual db, only when they come in as parameters.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? I think everything is fine with this code.

Comment: Looks correct to me as well.  However, these error messages are useless..
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: Oops. I think I know (it's a misprint in `UPDATE` - it should be `source.input_id`, not `source_input_id`). I'll update my answer

Comment: fixed that, but still same old error.  i feel as though maybe i messed up something above it, even though everything is exact same as many other SP's i've used.

Comment: that makes the two of us.  idk!

Comment: It looks ok to me. Can you post the whole sp definition in your question?

Comment: yes sir. it is updated with the new code and missing parts of the SP.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but the update is still giving me the same error.  Is this command compatible with sql server 2008?

Comment: @Greg: I've tried this procedure exactly as it is, without changing anything. The parser didn't complain. No syntax error. I mean, I didn't try to run it, I just created it, and there was no error messages. So count me in, because I, too, say: strange!

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need the `USING` clause?

See [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

Comment: thanks. i figured that might be a problem, but how would you actually code that?  I've looked at a few examples and tried out a few myself, but they don't seem to work for me.  How can I write the using if the condition I want is as above in the ON statement???

Answer (score 0):

```
merge DigitalTool 
using (select ID from Table_name) as tbl
ON tbl.ID = @ID
when matched then
    update
    set TOOL_ID = '@TOOL_ID',
        INPUT_ID = '@INPUT_ID'
when not matched then
    insert ( ID, TOOL_ID, INPUT_ID)
        values ( NEWID(), @TOOL_ID, @INPUT_ID )
```

Comment: i tried this and am still getting an error saying that there is incorrect syntax around "MERGE" and "AS".  is the problem that i am merging onto the same table that i am using?

Answer (score 0):

You have one `END` to much and the `MERGE` needs to be terminated with `;`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DigitalTool_InsertUpdate2
(@ID uniqueidentifier, @TOOL_ID uniqueidentifier, @INPUT_ID uniqueidentifier)

AS

MERGE 
INTO  DigitalTool as target
USING (SElECT @ID,@TOOL_ID,@INPUT_ID) as source(id, tool_id, input_id) 
ON (target.ID = source.id)
when matched then  
 update
  set TOOL_ID = source.tool_id,
    INPUT_ID = source.input_id
when not matched then
insert ( ID, TOOL_ID, INPUT_ID)
    values ( NEWID(), source.tool_id, source.input_id);
```